# Doctrine 2.9, Declaration of Proxies error (wrong function's prototypes)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating a website using :
- symfony/symfony 3.4
- doctrine/common 2.9

All works fine except for some entities which heritates from PHP classes with functions with default parameters.

For instance, I got an entity Document which extends a class Uploadable, which extends the PHP File class (which extends \SplFileInfo).

When generating the proxy for Document, Doctrine generate the following :

```
public function getBasename($suffix)
{

    $this->__initializer__ && $this->__initializer__->__invoke($this, 'getBasename', [$suffix]);

    return parent::getBasename($suffix);
}
```

My IDE (and Doctrine) show this error :
**Declaration should be compatible with SplFileInfo->getBasename([suffix : null|string = null])**

Any helps?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you redeclared the `getBasename` method in one of your classes? Can we see it?

Comment: Nope I haven't redeclare anything from File/SplFileInfo except getFilename/setFilename because my entity has a field "filename". May it be confused for Doctrine?

Comment: I tried to rename my field "filename" to "file" to create my own functions (with no redeclaration), same here :(

Comment: You can find the files here : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/33014960153850f82e457aaa069fde2820180722202741/54fb70

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I removed the "File" extends which was not really useful in my context (ie file upload).

I used a DataTransformer instead.